# Flink's hive streaming vs iceberg/hudi/delta

Tags: apache-flink, delta-lake, apache-iceberg, apache-hudi

There are some open sourced datake solutions that support crud/acid/incremental pull,such as Iceberg, Hudi, Delta. I think they have done what flink's hive streaming wants to do and even do better,

So, I would ask what the real power of flink's hive streaming provides over flink+iceberg/flink+hudi.Maybe flink+iceberg or flink+hudi hasn't been mature for now,but that is not a big issue, they will be mature soon.